# Third condition in if...else statement in PHP is not accessible

Tags: php

I am fairly new to PHP and I have been googling all day to find out what's wrong with my code but I was not able to find one that meets the output I wanted; to give you a better idea about my concern I have written my code below.

```
 <?php
 if (empty($lname) && empty($fname)) {
   echo"WARNING: Unable to save information, Blank fields found, Enter N/A if it is not applicable for the employee.";
 } else if ($query) {
   echo"WARNING: Unable to save information, Employee already exist in the database.";
 } else if ($save) {
   echo"$fname&nbsp;$lname's personal information saved succesfully.";
 }
 ?>
```

The first condition checks whether the value is blank, the second condition checks if value already exist in the database and the third condition saves the values if the two conditions above are not true.

All three conditions work if I run them one at a time, but when I put them together using the if...else statement, the third condition does not work.

I would like to ask for your assistance and enlighten me what I missed on my code.

Comment: What is the value of `$query`?

Comment: @john conde $query is a sql query. $select="SELECT EXISTS(SELECT LNAME,FNAME FROM perinfo WHERE LNAME='$lname' && FNAME='$fname' LIMIT 1)";
$query=mysql_query($select,$con);

Comment: A SQL query doesn't sound very false-y, does it? [Returns `true` on success, `false` on error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php#refsect1-function.mysql-query-returnvalues). A blank result set is still a successful query.

Comment: @sjagr i see, so what do you think is the best approach? do i need to assign one if statement for all three to meet the condition?

Comment: That makes no sense. The quickest (and I do mean _quickest_) fix for the problem**s** with your code is in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `$query` incorrectly. Use [`mysql_num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) to check the number of returned rows from your `SELECT` query:

```
if (empty($lname)&&empty($fname)) {
    echo "WARNING: Unable to save information, Blank fields found, Enter N/A if it is not applicable for the employee.";
} else if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
    echo "WARNING: Unable to save information, Employee already exist  in the database.";
} else if ($save) {
    echo "$fname&nbsp;$lname's personal information saved succesfully.";
}
```

Please note that `mysql_*` methods are deprecated and should be replaced with a more modern library. You can find many many topics on this with some quick searching and reviewing of the PHP docs (see the red box in my referenced `mysql_num_rows` link above?)

Comment: thanks for taking time on this; notifications and save are working correctly now but for some reason everytime each if statement is met it saves the info i enter what could wrong here? only the third condition should save the info why is that?

Comment: @ErphilCatama Not in the scope of your original question, sorry. You have to post a new question with relevant code that explains the saving behaviour (this question has none of that.)

Comment: alright no worries i will figure that out your help is greatly appreciated; new with stack overflow so please no vote down :(

Comment: @ErphilCatama Welcome to the SO community. Check out [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get better help with your questions and avoid downvotes!

Comment: thanks for advise :) ill check this out to avoid having one again

Comment: that link means a lot thanks a lot for the help.